# Buttons on trackpad don't work (Lenovo IdeaPad z410)

Tags: touchpad, drivers, hardware

Just installed Elementary and I'm really enjoying it - my only problem is that the buttons on the trackpad don't work. I am able to navigate by tapping the trackpad, but not by using the physical left/right buttons (which click). As far as I can tell it has a Synaptics track pad.